# how to connect R to mysql? do we need to install mysql on local host separately?

Tags: mysql, r

How to connect R to mysql? Do we need to install mysql on local host separately? When I try to connect it says

> "Error in .local(drv, ...) :    Failed to connect to database: Error:
>   Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (0)".

What does it mean? I am using R on windows by the way.

Comment: Which package are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by "install mysql on localhost separately"? Can you access mysql outside of R?

Comment: Enter "net start" on the command line. It will print out your server if it is there (along with other stuff.)

Comment: Dear JaimeCr. I am using R studio and I am not able to connect to Mysql from R. My question is- As I am not able to connect to Mysql on R do I need to download Mysql separately on my laptop and try to connect or Mysql is inbuilt with in R?

Comment: Dear Marichyasana. I tried using the net start key word and this is what it returned "Error: unexpected symbol in "net start"".

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your R code in the post so it is hard to "fix" what might be wrong. Instead I'll just show you some code that works.

To access a mysql database you can use the `RMySQL` package. For this to work your mysql server must accept remote requests and you must specify the

- address (for example the IP address where the server is running)
- the username
- the password
- the database name

Your mysql server should be set up to accept non-local requests unless it's already running locally on the machine where you run R.

```
library(RMySQL)
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user="username", password="PASSword",
                 dbname="dbname", host="192.168.13.15")
```

then you can submit queries in standard SQL language.

```
indata <- dbGetQuery(mydb, "select * from students")
```

You do not need a sql client for the R code to work, but if you cannot get it to run within R then you should try to see if you can log onto the server using a manual client. If that is not possible your server is not setup to allow the logins.

Comment: This is my code,followed by the error.                                                                                                                                                                                                   > library(RMySQL)
Warning message:
package ‘RMySQL’ was built under R version 3.3.1 
> mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user="admin", password="admin",
+                  dbname="admin", host="localhost")
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (0)

Comment: If the username, password, and database are all "admin" then I think the problem is not R-related but is an issue with your mysql server setting. Can you connect to the mysql server from the terminal with the above arguments?